# prev next pages for winforms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, browser

I'd like to implement the prev/next page behaviour for a winforms app like the browser prev/next pages

any existing code samples or guidance on where to start ?

I'd assume this is something already implemented and would not like to reinvent the wheel if possible

If the sample uses scsf/cab, that would be even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this when I wrote an Aero Wizard host. Basically the strategy was to keep a `List<T>` of `Panel`s that contained each page's controls, and that page `Panel` would be docked to a fixed `Panel` in the wizard. When the back button was clicked, I just replaced the contents of the host `Panel` with the previous `Panel` from the `List<T>`. And as users move "forward", just add the current page `Panel` to the list.

Comment: did you build it from scratch or used any base templates ?

Comment: Scratch, for Default Programs Editor. I'll open source it all at some point, but right now all I can give is advice :)

Comment: don't use vista much ( or at all ) but looks good
didn't know it's a separate download too, would it work on xp ?

looks like right now i've to cleanup and ship without the browsing part, may revisit it later

Answer (score 2):

Use TabPane, Panel or any other container control. Show or hide them or use Zorder.